Vanishing Ideal of a $\overline{k}$-Variety defined over $k$
Let $k$ a base field and $K:=\overline{k}$ its algebraic closure. Let $Z:=V(I) \subset \Bbb A^n_K$ an affine subvariety defined by vanishing ideal $I \subset K[X_1,..., X_n]$ and assume that topologically the set $Z(k)$ of $k$- valued points in dense in $Z$.
Let $I^m \subset K[X_1,..., X_n]_m$ ($m \in \Bbb N$) be the $K$-vector subspace of polynomials in $I$ whose degree is $\le m$.
Question: How to see that $I^m$ can be generated/ admits a $K$-basis by polynomials in $K[X_1,..., X_n]_m$ with coefficients in $k$ using that $Z(k)$ is dense?
Motivation: This argument in used in proof of Lemma 7.2 in these notes.
Ideas: The putative argument seems to depend crucially on finiteness of $I^m$ as $K$-space; otherwise, why should one else introduce $I^m$ as "auxilary spaces" if thats not a matter of $K$-finiteness. We can let Galois group of $K/k$ act on $K[X_1,..., X_n]$ via $ (g^*a)(v):= a(g^{-1}(v))$ where $a \in K[X_1,..., X_n], v \in \Bbb A_K^n(K)$. Clearly, this action preserves degree, so descends to action on finite $K$-space $K[X_1,..., X_n]_m$. Using density of $Z(k)$ in $Z$ and continuity of of polynomials (as maps $\Bbb A_K^n \to K$) we can show that the Galois action restricts to $I$, resp. $I^m$.
Idea not to continue? A guess: Can we even show that Galois Action fixes a set of gen's of $I^m$?
#UPDATE: Think the question can be regarded as solved, unfortunately, I read the proof not attentive enough. The idea is just that by density of $Z(k)$ we find enough points in $Z(k)$ (so tautologically with coords in $k$) imposing enough linear equations with coeffs in $k$ forming a $d \times r(m)$ matrix $W$ with $k$-valued entries, where $d$ dimension of $Z$ and $r(m)$ wimension of  $K[X_1,..., X_n]_m$. Solving $A \cdot v=0$, gives a $k$-space $L$ whose $K$-span contains $I^m$. But, due to density of $Z(k)$ it looks easy to actually show that the  $K$-span $L$ coincides with $I^m$.

If you’ve resolved this, then you should post the explanation as an answer or delete the question.

@Daniel: Think the technique is rather nice due to its elementality, as it makes no usage of Galois descent as "heavy weapon" as one usually would approach that kind of issues.

(Just a copy of added update part above): The idea is just that by density of $Z(k)$ in $Z$we find enough points in $Z(k) (\subset \Bbb A^n_K(k)$ (so tautologically with coords in $k$) imposing (via evaluating canon basis elements $X_1^{m_1} \cdot ... X_n^{m_n}$ - with $\sum_im_i=m$ - in coods of elements of $Z(k)$ ) enough linear equations with coeffs in $k$ forming a $d \times r(m)$ matrix $W$ with $k$-valued entries, where $d$ dimension of $Z$ and $r(m)$ dimension of  $K[X_1,..., X_n]_m$. Solving $A \cdot v=0$, gives a $k$-space $L$ whose $K$-span contains $I^m$. But, due to density of $Z(k)$ it looks easy to actually show that the  $K$-span $L$ coincides with $I^m$.
